# DllRegisterServer entry point was not found - when registering a Vb.NET DLL?

Tags: .net, dll, vb6, activex

I wrote a dll in vb.net that calls a web service, consumes the data returned then passes results back to the calling program. I originally wrote in in VS 2008, on windows 7 (x64). Tested it in a vb 6 program also written on windows 7 and everything worked. The vb6 program got the data and I could move on.

The real world for me though is to use this dll inside another dll written in vb 6. I get the error "ActiveX component can't create object" when I get to the code

`Dim myWebService as webService.ComClass1

Set myWebService = New webService.ComClass1`

I've recompiled my code on windowsXP (x86) and recopied over the .dll and .tlb.

When I try to register the dll I get an error: 'DllRegisterServer entry point was not found'. The .tlb seems to register fine in VB as far as adding a reference to it and the intellesense works too.

Does anyone have any ideas what I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't register .NET assemblies with Regsvr32.exe.  You have to use Regasm.exe, you'll find the tool in the framework directory.  Use the /codebase option if you don't put the assembly in the GAC.  You shouldn't on a dev machine.

This worked okay before probably because you let Visual Studio do it for you.

Comment: I tried using the /codebase option, but I got an error saying it's not signed.  How do I do that?  Also, I now get an error saying "Automation error.  The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: It is not an error, it is a warning.  It means "are you sure you don't mind dealing with DLL Hell?"  Right now you don't, you only have one.  Not sure what file it cannot find, maybe you didn't use /codebase after you got the warning?  You can use SysInternals' ProcMon tool to see what it is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't register a .net DLL the same as a VB6 dll. .NET DLL's don't have the tlb inside them, it's separate.

Instead, use REGASM on .net dlls. it's on your computer, but you'll need to do a search to find it, as it's not on the path by default.